# how to maintain dimension size of jpanel with GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, gridbaglayout

Here is my code. When I resize the program the other layouts, it works fine except for the `CheckPanel` (with `GridBagLayout`); somehow it became bigger. How can I handle this?

Advance Thanks.

```
JPanel CheckPanel = new JPanel();
CheckPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
GridBagConstraints gbc_CheckPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_CheckPanel.gridwidth = 2;
gbc_CheckPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_CheckPanel.gridx = 0;
gbc_CheckPanel.gridy = 1;
CenterPanel.add(CheckPanel, gbc_CheckPanel);
CheckPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6, 0, 0));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you perhaps set a gbc.weighty = 0; somewhere in the code before this?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint

```
gbc_CheckPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

tells the GridBagLayout to let this component use any available extra space (also depending on its preferred- and maximum size). Using `GridBagConstraints.NONE` or `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL` could solve this, but you still have to decide which component will receive the extra space.

EDIT: Based on the comments, it is still not clear how the other components are inserted, and how the distribution of extra space is specified. In this example, the `weighty` fields are used to say that the table should receive all extra space. Maybe it helps to identify differences to the original program:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CheckboxConstraints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        fill(centerPanel);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        f.getContentPane().add(centerPanel);

        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void fill(JPanel centerPanel)
    {
        addSearchBar(centerPanel);
        addCheckBoxPanel(centerPanel);
        addTable(centerPanel);
    }


    private static void addSearchBar(JPanel centerPanel)
    {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = null;
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        centerPanel.add(new JButton("Search"), gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        centerPanel.add(new JTextField(), gbc);
    }

    private static void addCheckBoxPanel(JPanel centerPanel)
    {
        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel();
        checkPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_CheckPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_CheckPanel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_CheckPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_CheckPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_CheckPanel.gridy = 1;
        gbc_CheckPanel.weighty = 0;
        centerPanel.add(checkPanel, gbc_CheckPanel);
        checkPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6, 0, 0));

        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C0"));
        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C1"));
        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C2"));
        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C3"));
        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C4"));
        checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("C5"));
    }

    private static void addTable(JPanel centerPanel)
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] {
            {"C00", "C01" },
            {"C00", "C01" },
        }, new Object[]{ "H0", "H1" });
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming that the 'Search' panel and the Table-Panel are both also added to the CenterPanel: Are you setting any weights (particularly, `weighty`) for the GridBagConstraints? You might consider setting a `weighty` of 0.0 for the search- and checkbox panel, and 1.0 for the table panel. Otherwise, an http://sscce.org/ might help to find a solution.

Comment: Search , Table and Checkpanel is in the same panel(GridBagLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
gbc_CheckPanel.fill =GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL
```

and to adjust the space vertically

```
gbc_CheckPanel.ipady = 20;  //Not sure this works in your case but this should fix the resizing issue
```

Another solution is to add a new JPanel with BorderLayout and insert the panel with JCheckBoxes using the constraint `BorderLayout.NORTH` and the table with constraint `BorderLayout.CENTRE`